# Writing a function with if() in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I want to create a funtion that accepts two inputs (a dataframe and a string). Moreover, if the string is equal to `"cols"`  this function need to return the number of columns, othwerwise it need to be return the number of rows.

My code is:

```
wl_df <- function(df,string) {
  if(string == "cols")
    return(ncol(df))
} else {
  return(nrow(df))

}
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
Error: unexpected 'else' in:
"        return(ncol(df))
    } else"
```

,

```
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

and,

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
```

Why do I get these errors, and how can I fix them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing an opening `{`, try `if (string == "cols") {`. You're also missing a closing brace at the end to match your `function(df,string) {`.

Comment: @r2evans or just get rid of the line `} else {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an opening `{` on the `if` line, and a closing brace from either `else` or the function itself. While you *do* have a matching count of `{` to `}`, they are not paired correctly.

Try:

```r
wl_df <- function(df,string) {
  if (string == "cols") {
    return(ncol(df))
  } else {
    return(nrow(df))
  }
}
```

Or, as @AllanCameron aptly suggested:

```r
wl_df <- function(df,string) {
  if (string == "cols") return(ncol(df)) else return(nrow(df))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, same function but in a more compact way:

```
wl_df <- function(df, string) ifelse(string == "cols", ncol(df), nrow(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize it, if you want to hit a whole list of data frames.

```
@library(tidyverse)
dfTests <- list(mtcars, iris, diamonds)

wl_df <- function(dfs,string) {
  map_dbl(dfs,
    ~ case_when(
        string == "cols" ~ ncol(.x),
        string == "rows" ~ nrow(.x),
        TRUE             ~ NA))
}

# R > wl_df(dfTests, "cols")
# [1] 11  5 10
# R > wl_df(dfTests, "rows")
# [1]    32   150 53940
```